# fullscreen true in config.xml get ignored

Tags: cordova

I'm using cordova 3.5.0 and testing on a Samsung S5. Both of these setting in the config.xml get ignored:

```
<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
<preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
```

Any ideas?